# Spring JPA/Hibernate org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Entity (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, interceptor

Experts/Gurus/Friends

Our application runs with Spring 3.2, JPA 2, Hibernate 4.2 tech stack with MySQL & Tomcat 7. We are getting a weird exception which is quite a puzzle to solve. We have a very simple entity which works well through Junit test without any issues. But when I added Hibernate EmptyInterceptor (moved the common company logic in here) then I get the below mentioned exception.. Alternatively I even tried with Hibernate PreInsertEventListener also but same exception.

After reading few posts in stackoverflow - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855542/org-hibernate-assertionfailure-null-id-in-entry-dont-flush-the-session-after) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855542/org-hibernate-assertionfailure-null-id-in-entry-dont-flush-the-session-after) and [few others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784271/how-to-remove-null-id-entry-dont-flush-the-session-after-an-exception-occu), it makes me to think that read operation using EntityManager (in Interceptor) is triggering auto flush which causes exception to be thrown. But couldn't identify what it is. Also I have remove any not null constrains in this simple Entity class as well as in table (which dont even have a foreign key).

**MYSQL Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE  `rcent_rel_2`.`worklist_status_master` (
              `worklist_status_seqid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `worklist_status_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
              `created_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
              `updated_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              `updated_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
              `comp_seq_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `created_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`worklist_status_seqid`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Simple Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="worklist_status_master")
public class WorklistStatusDO  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorklistStatusDO.class);

    private Integer id;
    private String workListStatusName;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) -- Tried this too
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="worklist_status_seqid")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="worklist_status_name")
    public String getWorkListStatusName() {
        return workListStatusName;
    }
    public void setWorkListStatusName(String workListStatusName) {
        this.workListStatusName = workListStatusName;
    }
    public WorklistStatusDO workListStatusName(String workListStatusName) {
        setWorkListStatusName(workListStatusName);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this).
                add("workListStatusName", getWorkListStatusName()).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj || (obj instanceof WorklistStatusDO && obj.hashCode() == hashCode()));
    }
}
```

**Junit working scenairo**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value =  "classpath*:/spring/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class WorklistStatusTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void saveWorklistStatus(){
        CompanyInfo.setCompanyName("ABC");
        UserInfo.setUserId("XYZ");

        WorklistStatusDO worklistStatus = new WorklistStatusDO();
        worklistStatus.workListStatusName("test");

        // Company Logic
        javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select c From CompanyMasterDO c Where c.companyName =:companyName");
        query.setParameter("companyName", CompanyInfo.getCompanyName());
        CompanyMasterDO companyMasterDO = (CompanyMasterDO) query.getSingleResult();

        assertThat(companyMasterDO).isNotNull();

        entityManager.persist(worklistStatus);
    }

}
```

**Junit failing scenario due to below Exception after moving Company Logic out to Interceptor**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value =  "classpath*:/spring/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class WorklistStatusTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void saveWorklistStatus(){
        CompanyInfo.setCompanyName("ABC");
        UserInfo.setUserId("XYZ");

        WorklistStatusDO worklistStatus = new WorklistStatusDO();
        worklistStatus.workListStatusName("test");

        // Company Logic moved to Interceptor

        entityManager.persist(worklistStatus);
    }

}
```

**EmptyInterceptor**

```
@Named
@Transactional
public class AuditEmptyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

        System.out.println("*********************inside OnSave() in Audit Empty Interceptor******************");
        javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select c From CompanyMasterDO c Where c.companyName =:companyName");
        query.setParameter("companyName", CompanyInfo.getCompanyName());
        CompanyMasterDO companyMasterDO = (CompanyMasterDO) query.getSingleResult();

        return false;
    }
```

**Exception**

```
    org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.work.WorklistStatusDO entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1205)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1262)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:287)
    at com.company.demo.audit.AuditEmptyInterceptor.onSave(AuditEmptyInterceptor.java:45)
    at com.company.demo.audit.StaticDelegateInterceptor.onSave(StaticDelegateInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.substituteValuesIfNecessary(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.rcent.test.worklist.WorklistStatusTest.saveWorklistStatus(WorklistStatusTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Note:

Had an issue earlier with injecting EmptyInterceptor. This is now solved [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274356/spring-jpa-hibernate-emptyinterceptor-not-injecting-entitymanager-spring-beans). Thanks to Ricardo.

Comment: Updated the SQL for the table.. As you may see there is no Foreign key at all. Simple PK is the only field that is not null.

Comment: The problem is related to [HB-1066](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1066), but it shouldn't matter, the answer I just added (using EventListeners) should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a Hibernate EventListener instead of Interceptors:

```
@Component
public class AuditEventListener implements PersistEventListener, DeleteEventListener, MergeEventListener, PreInsertEventListener {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

     @Override 
     public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
          return false; 
     } 

     @Override
     public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) {
        // you business logic
     }

     ... 
     ...
}
```

You can register the listener using this bean:

```
@Component
public class HibernateListenerRegistrar {
   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

   @Autowired
   private AuditEventListener auditEventListener;

   @PostConstruct
   public void registerListeners() {
      if(entityManagerFactory instanceof HibernateEntityManagerFactory) {
          final HibernateEntityManagerFactory  hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory;
          final SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory =  (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
          final EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
          registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST).appendListener(auditEventListener);
          registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.MERGE).appendListener(auditEventListener);
          registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.DELETE).appendListener(auditEventListener);
          registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(auditEventListener);
          // register other events here
      }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This approach won't work if you want to perform queries during the PRE_INSERT event and your IDs are generated by the database. If you manually generate Ids (or fetch them from the database before the transaction), you should be able to perform queries on during PRE_INSERT without problem. I've tested this using manually assigned IDs.

Depending on what your audit requirement is, you probably could implement the logic during the PERSIST event (which occurs after Hibernate has generated the IDs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. As I mentioned above, I have attempted this already and funny thing is that I was getting the same exception. Infact I jumped from PersistEventListener option to EmptyInterceptor as I couldnt proceed. I am totally stunned when I encountered the same exception again. :) So this makes me to strongly believe that when you try to do a search in either of these listener or interceptor, Hibernate does a flush without setting auto generated id field. Hmmm dont know how to proceed. Just wanted to do it in a clean way.. ;)

Comment: Can you update the version of hibernate? I have a working implementation of this concept using exactly the code I posted above working on version 4.3.5.Final.

Comment: So I have updated Hibernate core, entitymanager, ehcache updated to 4.3.5 Final and updated hibernate-jpa to 2.1.0.0 Final. Is there any other updates needed ? Because I am getting ClassNotFoundException - org.hibernate.service.api.BasicServiceInitiator. Any clue here ? Couple of Hibernate bugs have been opened on this - [HHH-9157](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9157) and [1386](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1386)

Comment: Make sure you are using `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` 1.0.0.Final instead of `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api`

Comment: Hi Ricardo.. Hope ur doing good. I was able to upgrade to Hibernate ORM to 4.3.5 Final and Hibernate JPA to 2.1.0.0 Final. So I was able to run the unit test. But only the onPersist(Event e) got invoked by hibernate and onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent e) method is not called when persisting the entity using entityManager. Any guess here ? Can you test in your code base if onPreInsert method is triggered or not ?

Comment: Sure, I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: Got it, you need to register your listener for the EventType.PRE_INSERT) by adding the following line `registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(auditEventListener);` to the 'registerListeners()' in 'HibernateListenerRegistrar' class. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hahaa.. Thats right.. I have now registered the Pre_insert as you mentioned and now the call gets into this pre-insert method. But same old exception again (org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id - (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Could you please try doing a entityManager fetch in pre-insert menthod and see if you are getting  the same exception ? I once again guess that reading just before saving forces a flush which results in this exception.

Comment: I just tested doing a query from the preInsertMethod and it worked in my code. I'm not sure if it will make any difference but my entities are using ids with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Comment: I tried with GenerationType.IDENTITY already and even now. But no luck. Dont know why it is attempting to flush..

Comment: @Priya, I finally managed to test this in isolation, and I can confirm I'm also getting the same exception during PRE_INSERT. The difference was that my code performed queries on PERSIST no on PRE_INSERT. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo for your response. So I circumvent the problem by having the query done early so that object tree has the proper values before persist. But glad that we found something that may not work straight forward.

Comment: This saved my day: I used it together with Spring-Boot.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that an ID is not being generated. Also some databases do not like user using column names called 'id'.

Try using the id generator annotation in this way:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="seqMyObject")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqMyObject", sequenceName="TBBROKERCONTACTSYNC_SEQ")
```

In the above snippet I am using a database sequence.

Also give these a go.

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
private Long id;
```

OR

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

MYSQL uses the identity strategy to auto increment.

Comment: Can you confirm that you get the same exception when using @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)?

Comment: It will also be helpful to know which specific hibernate 4.2.x version are you using.

Comment: Thx @Kush for your response. But auto generation works so cool across 50+ entities in my application and this one also unless I introduce the fetch part to EmptyInterceptor (which triggers autoflush I think). Also I m using mysql and the unlike other commercial DBs, I believe mysql dont allow you to have explicit sequence created. All you need to mention is the index column which needs to be auto incremented. I have updated the post with table sql.

Comment: Thx Ricardo for your response. yes I tried with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) but no success and my hibernate version is 4.2.6.Final. As you may see only when I move the simple fetch query to EmptyInterceptor this is happening. (I need to move this logic as it would be more appropriate for auditing in a central place).

Comment: Since there I are other differences in my code (I'm using `Spring 4.0.6` and `Spring Data Jpa 1.6.2`) I will try to create a minimal sample project and upload it to github or bitbucket.

Comment: Wow that would be simply a gr8 help if you could get it. But I am using Spring 3.2.4.Release and plain JPA 2.1.0.Final, Hibernate 4.2.6.Final..

Answer (score 0):

This error is EVEN possible, when DB is read only and a write operation is tried.